# UISegment Control in UITableView Prototype cell, when value is changed in Segment control the scroll is moved to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a screen, where we are displaying questions with YES or NO. For Yes Or No we have used UISegment Control.
When a value is changes in the UISegment Control the scroll is moved to Top of the screen, when we have more questions and when we select last or but last as shown in the image.

Below is the code used to render the controls.

Link to the videos how the output looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSRdR.jpg .

Please help me how can i remove the scroll movement on selection of new value in segment control.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return timeOutQuestions.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell* )tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    static NSString* questionTableIdentifier=@"SegmentCell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: questionTableIdentifier];
    
    if(cell == nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:questionTableIdentifier];
         cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
         cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
      }
    
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0 , cell.bounds.size.width , 0.0, -cell.bounds.size.width);
       
    Question* currentQuestion=[[shared getQuestions:questionSet] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    @try{
        UISegmentedControl *segment = [[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = [[questionSegmentControl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue];
        [segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        
        UILabel *label = [[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
        label.text = currentQuestion.questionText;
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }@catch(NSException* ex){
        NSLog(@"%@",ex.reason);
    }
    
    if(changeOffSet && indexChangedValue.row > 2){
        [self.questionTableView setContentOffset:tableContentOffSet animated:NO];
         [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:true];
        changeOffSet = false;
    }
    
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    NSInteger selectedSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    CGPoint senderOriginInTableView = [questionTableView convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:sender];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [questionTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:senderOriginInTableView];
    indexChangedValue = indexPath;
    tableContentOffSet = self.questionTableView.contentOffset;
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:false];
    changeOffSet = true;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSRdR.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the scrolling programatically with this

```
[self.questionTableView setContentOffset:tableContentOffSet animated:NO];
```

I think you need to rework it a bit. Stop changing the content offset and see how it goes. Also, maybe you need to get rid of this line

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

which I think also interferes with the scrolling.